# Mocking a method that has optional parameter

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, moq

I have a method `public void SendMail(string email, string subject, string body, List<Attachment> attachements = null)` where last parameter can be `null` or `List<Attachment>`.

I mocked it like this:

```
        var mailMock = new Mock<IMailService>();
        mailMock.Setup(m => m.SendMail(It.IsNotNull<string>(), It.IsNotNull<string>(), It.IsNotNull<string>(), It.IsAny<List<Attachment>>())).Verifiable();
        mailMock.Verify();
```

But it doesn't allow `null` values in attachment parameter. How can I allow both `null` and `List<Attachment>` to be passed?

UPDATE: Actually, it is working, it's just that I invoked `mailMock.Verify();` too early, before actual call to tested method.

Comment: Which version of Moq are you using?

Comment: Yep, it should work.